# What does '@@' mean in windbg scripting

Tags: debugging, windbg

In windbg scripting, a single '@' obtains the value as described [here](https://www.dumpanalysis.org/WCDA/WCDA-Sample-Chapter.pdf):

> . If you want to obtain the pseudo-register value then use @ symbol, for example,
> @$t0.

However, I was unable to find an explanation for '@@'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@@` and specify the language using `@@masm(...)` or `@@c++(...)` (see [MASM numbers and operators (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/masm-numbers-and-operators#numeric-operators-in-masm-expressions)), which is likely a good choice if you read the rest.

Using `@@` without any language specifier is a bit tricky, because it will use the opposite one than chosen to be the default. The default default language would be MASM, so `@@` switches to C++ in that case. Except you have changed the default language to C++, in which case `@@` would switch to MASM. Changing the default is possible via the [`-ee` command line argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/windbg-command-line-options) or the [`.expr` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-expr--choose-expression-evaluator-).

Answer (score 1):

The `@@` directive instructs windbg to parse the command differently.
Instead of using the traditional MASM parsing syntax (i.e use the value) the `@@` instructs windbg to use the C++ parsing syntax which is similar to dereferencing in C pointers.